# Hardware selection for acquiring signal in digital form

Tags: sampling

I want to it clear that I am a mechanical engineer and so my knowledge on electronics and signal processing is limited. I am working in a hydrophone system. My job is to find the position of an underwater pinger with an AUV. The pinger sends the sound at a frequency of 45kHz and my hydrophone send signals in range of 0-5mV. I have doubts regarding what implementation of the anti-alisiang filter, signal conditioning, ADC conversion and digital filters for removing noise in terms of hardware. I do know that the sampling frequency should be minimal double that of the signal but that us not enough and aiming at 1MHz I am struggling to find a microcontroller board with such specs. Also, I need simultaneously sampling of two hydrophones depending on the difference in the time the signal takes to reach the two hydrophones, I would calculate the angle at which the pinger is present. Basically, I need help figuring out the hardware required to get such results.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz is an expert on sonar. So probably he could design you the necessary system...

Comment: First, to clear up a misconception: sampling at 2X the frequency only works for infinite length signals (longer than the life of the universe).  The shorter your ping, the higher the needed sample rate, as shorter time envelopes have wider frequency responses than 2X the carrier frequency.